# Get all values of list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have list of dictionaries like this:

```
count = [{'A': 0}, {'B': 2}, {'C': 4}]
```

I want convert `count` to something like this:

```
count = [0, 2, 4]
```

Comment: I would be looking to fix this upstream - the heterogeneity here makes this harder than it needs to be. Where does the list come from? Are the dictionaries always a single key-value pair (and then why are they dictionaries)?

Comment: Please show what you tried and ask a specific question about an issue you had. [Ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with list comprehension:

```
count = [{'A': 0}, {'B': 2}, {'C': 4}]
[j for i in count for j in i.values()]
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the values from each dictionary using a comprehension, and then you can use `itertools.chain()` to extract the values from each dictionary into one long iterator. This gives us a `chain` object, which we need to turn into a list using `list()`.

```py
from itertools import chain

list(chain.from_iterable(item.values() for item in count))
```

This outputs:

```py
[0, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Why would you bother doing this when it is slower than just doing list comprehension by itself, and that's not accounting for the import?

Comment: Because [some](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#274-decision) consider multiple statements in a comprehension to be poor style, and this is still (roughly) as concise.